# Jquery hide() function show on page load

Tags: jquery

Scenario:
I've a page with multiple DIVs. Some of the DIVs should be hidden on first page load. I've used Jquery hide() function to hide the DIVs.

Problem:
For some reason the jquery hide function seems to be working only partially i.e. the DIV that needs to be hidden completely shows for a second and hides.

Is there anyway to resolve this please?

Comment: You can try CSS? `div.hide { display: none; }`. jQuery will run only after DOM is ready.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your javascript won't be executed until the DOM is ready (you can't hide an element that doesn't exist yet) so the browser renders it then hides it. Depending on how fast your browser is and how efficient your code is you may or may not notice it.

A far better solution is to have the element be hidden from it is loaded, using css.

```
#elementId { display:none; }
```

You would include this rule within style tags with the rest of your css. If you have many elements that you want to hide/show, give them all a common class name; then you can toggle their visibility all at once. The css for that would be:

```
.commonClassName { display:none; }
```

Then in your jQuery you can call `.show()` to show them, or `.toggle()` to toggle their visibility on/off. The jQuery class selector is identical to the css one:

```
$('.commonClassName').show();
```

**Note:** You can also make styling changes using the html style attribute:
`style="display:none;"` But, for the reasons I outline in the comments, this is usually not the route to take.

Comment: Google Developers advise to put small snippets of code inline. Code such as this one (simple display: block;) is great to put inline (and possibly faster (?)).

Comment: @bram It probably would be faster inline. But with the class selector it would have to be in style tags. In any case if the OP already had css for the page, it seems more intuitive to have all of it in one place, since other rules can be added to target that selector without rewriting it and it is easier to make changes. Also if the css is in an external file it can be minified, cached, etc. which will *definitely* be faster. All in all, I think it makes more sense to adopt the habit of *not* using inline styles (I will update and share the alternative though :P)

Comment: @nbrooks I agree. I'm not fond of inline styles (actually, I rarely use them) but I was working on page load optimisation and stumbled upon Google's rules which stated that small inline snippets are good. :)